# can i flush the session after closing the session in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session

```
session.close();
session.flush();
```

Which gave an exception Session is closed.

Or Should we flush the session before closing the session only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No..session should be flushed before closing connection.
Session flush basically synchronize cache data with database without committing data and flush should be called inside transaction

Comment: Thanks, but what is meant by without committing here, If you dont commit, what is the use?